# C# - Keep track of auto incrementing variable between serialization and deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization, static-variables, auto-increment

I am working on a project and need help with regards to auto incrementing ID fields.

In terms of serialization, what is the best way to get the ID from when it was last serialized when it comes to deserialization of a static variable that you have been auto incrementing upon each instantiation of a class.

For instance...

```
[Serializable]
class Category
{
    private static int iCatID = 0;
    private int iCategoryID;
    private string sCategory;

    public Category(string _sCategory)
    {
        iCatID++;
        iCategoryID = iCatID;
        sCategory = _sCategory;
    }
}
```

I learnt the hard way that after creating 5 or so instances of this class, I serialized it, then deserialized and expected `iCatID` to pick up where it left off when I started creating more instances of the class, but it had of course reset back to 0.

What I want to know is how do I keep track of an auto incrementing variable in between serialization and deserialization and what would be best practice?

I've thought of two ways to possibly do it:

1. When serializing the class, save the value of the static variable to a global setting and get that value again and set the static variable from the global setting on deserialization.
2. When deserializing the class, use linq to query all instances of the class and get the highest number and then set the static variable accordingly.

I'm sure that there's a more elegant way of dealing with this.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Did the question change? I don't recall `iCategoryID` being in the original version; either way, you aren't actually assigning a value to `iCategoryID` at any point... so we should *expect* the value to be 0, no?

Comment: It wasn't meant to be in there. I've taken it out now. Thanks :-)

Comment: Actually sorry yes it should be in there. I also added how I'm using it in the constructor. I don't think it will change the basis of the question though. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization is about instances... if you took a *snapshot* then it would be stored, i.e.

```
static int nextCatID;
private readonly int catID;
private string category;
...
public Category(string category)
{
    catID = Interlocked.Increment(ref nextCatID);
    this.category = category
}
```

here `catID` is the value related to the individual instance - and would be serialized and deserialized; of course, it could then lead to repeats: if you serialize item 1 and then deserialize it 5 times, you'll have 5 more "item 1"s.

If you wanted the value to be *set during deserialization*, you can do that too - just mark the field as non-serialized:

```
static int nextCatID;
[NonSerialized]
private int catID;
```

and set it in a post-serialization callback using the same code from the constructor (note that because the callback is *not* a constructor, you can't use `readonly`):

```
[OnDeserialized()]
private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
{
    catID = Interlocked.Increment(ref nextCatID);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. I'll give it a crack tomorrow to see what results are yielded from this implementation. Many thanks.

Comment: The only problem is if he is using the Id to connect multiple items.

Comment: @xanatos indeed, which is why I presented two *different* approaches, depending on whether the intent was is reproduce them as they were when serialized, or whether the intent is to give all objects new identities when they are deserialized

Comment: @ShaneBatey btw, the `Interlocked.Increment` is actually pretty important here; your current code is not thread-safe and would not work reliably if used, say, within ASP.NET or WCF (or some other inherently threaded environment)

Comment: Fantastic! It worked! Thank you very much for your help. I tried the second implementation after the first one didn't work how I wanted it to. In my studies I had read about using a static variable as an auto incrementer, but when it came to using it alongside serialization I had no clue. I thought that this would have been covered but alas you have come to the rescue, thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
private static long iCatID = DateTime.Utc.Ticks;
```

start your counter with the current time (UTC) converted in a `long`. So at any run of your program with a little luck (if your user hasn't changed the clock), all the new IDs will be > all the old IDs.

Note that by using UTC you are resistant to changes of Summer Time/Winter Time.

Another solution is to simply forget about `Id` and use `Guid`.

You generate it through `Guid.NewGuid()` and it will be unique. The only problem is that you have just lost the ordering of items. You can't simply compare two `Guid` and tell "this is newer, this is older". You can tell that they are equal/different.

Comment: Seems like a good idea but there could be chances that one user could access the serialized file, save it, then a friend on the other side of the world accesses the same file which depending on time zone could cause issues. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ShaneBatey If their clock is correctly setted, then it isn't a problem, because the UTC time is absolute in the world. This is the reason I used `DateTime.Utc` and not `DateTime`. `DateTime.Utc` now is the same in New York, London, Tokyo, ...

Comment: Ahh I see. A valid option then. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but I selected the other answer. It was more like what I was looking for. But your answer is good too. I would vote it up but I do not have enough reputation points yet. Thanks :-)